# Creating a TortoiseSVN Start Commit local hook script to run .bat file, cannot find path specified

Tags: batch-file, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to have TortoiseSVN run a .bat file before all commits using a start commit hook. I defined it by right clicking the folder -> Properties ->Subversion -> Properies... -> Created a new hook script.

[image]

I've tried several different commands...

```
WScript "%REPOROOT+%\precommit.bat"
VBScript "%REPOROOT+%\precommit.bat"
%REPOROOT+%\precommit.bat
```

Though none have worked, I keep getting that the file was not found. I'm not sure if REPOROOT is not defined or what?

Even doing

echo "%REPOROOT%" gives the error.

[image]

Comment: Has the hook script been committed to the repository? Has it been checked out to the local working copy? I never succeeded with `%REPOROOT+%`, but it works with `%REPOROOT%`, given that the relative path of the script is the one in the repository. To call a batch file, your thirt attempt is the right one. Doing `echo "%REPOROOT%"` in the script cannot succeed, because it does not receive this value, it is a TortoiseSVN-internal thing (and you needed to redirect it to `> con`!)...

Comment: It still gives the error popup shown. It hasn't been committed to the repo yet because we don't want to mess up the entire teams work right now until it works. I mean I think the %REPOROOT% is the trunk in the root folder, it's the first directory with the TortSVN checkmark/exclamation point. I've tried doing both %REPOROOT%\trunk\precommit.bat and just %REPOROOT%\precommit.bat but no luck.

Comment: `%REPOROOT%` points to the root, but not to the trunk, so if your script is in the trunk, specify `%REPOROOT%/trunk/precommit.bat`; it is important to use *forward-slashes*! it seems the script does not even have to be committed as I first assumed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "%REPOROOT+%/precommit.bat" fixed the issue. Combination of needing to use forward slashes as suggested in comments and also using double quotes.